# How to print &(ampersand) symbol in properties file

Tags: java, swing, properties

I am printing a label from properties file which has and & sign, i.e., I want to print the label as "*sale & care*", but the & ampersand symbol would not appear on the Swing screen. I'm new to Swing. When I do it this way "*sale && care*" the system hangs.

The key value structure in properties file looks like this: `saleandcare.label = sale & care`

Comment: Try &amp; instead of &

Comment: i did, e.g., saleandcare.label = sale &amp; care  ... Still does not works..

Comment: @Sudhanshu Unless it's an XML file, which by the format given it isn't, that suggestion cannot possibly work.

Comment: nopes... it would print 38; .. tried it too.

Comment: in which swing component are you trying to display it? Can you post the code snippet?

Comment: I tried "&sale && care ", it worked.. Thanks all :)

Comment: In what kind of component are you displaying this text?  That character is not special in any way and does not need to be escaped, unless you are embedding it in HTML.  There is nothing in Swing, or java.util.Properties, which interprets "&&" as "&".

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
saleandcare.label = <html>sale &amp care</html>
```

instead of

```
saleandcare.label = sale & care
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Is it not supposed to have semicolons at the end `&amp;`?